# Very simple .htaccess mod_rewrite configuration gives 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

Ok, I'm starting to think that the problem is me but... ¿What's wrong here?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule testpage\.html http://www.google.com [R] #It works
RewriteRule ^mineral/([0-9]+)/?$ ver.php?id=$1 [NC,L] #It doesn't
```

I have a folder called "WebX" and this .htaccess inside it along with other files from the web.
mod_rewrite is working ok according to phpinfo and everything is running on localhost.
The most courious thing is that if I type `localhost/WebX/testpage.html` it redirects to Google
but unfortunately for me if I type `localhost/WebX/mineral/1` it gives me 404. ¿What happens?

Comment: Does ver.php exist?

Does the redirect to Google still work if you change the first rule to ^testpage\.html$ ?

Comment: ver.php exists (I just checked right now, maybe I could changed its name but no, exists and works) and yes, it still working if I put "^" before "testpage". ¿What can it be?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is caused by `RewriteBase /`. Your `.htaccess` is in a subdirectory `/WebX/`, but you are telling mod_rewrite to rewrite rules as if the current directory was `/`. It tries to load a file `ver.php` in your www-root, which doesn't exist. If you have verbose error messages with what file it tried to load, you'll notice it says that it tried to load `/ver.php` and not `/WebX/ver.php` as you might expect.

The rest you are doing, most notably using a relative url instead of a `/` prefixed absolute url, seems correct. The correct `.htaccess` to use would be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /WebX/
RewriteRule testpage\.html http://www.google.com [R] #It works
RewriteRule ^mineral/([0-9]+)/?$ ver.php?id=$1 [NC,L] #It now should work
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your interesting and for you answer. Unfortunately it still not working, with the same problem. One thing I forgot to say is that the 404 error refers to "mineral" as a directory, it doesn't talk about ver.php. The error is like `The requested URL /WebX/mineral/1 was not found on this server.` ver.php, the "id", and the "1" parameter exist.

Comment: Where does `/pacoWeb/` come from?!

Comment: It's the real directory name, I prefer talk about WebX, it's easier for me

Comment: I assume you changed `WebX` in my code then too. The fact that it gives that page name and not something with `ver.php` in it, means that the rule doesn't match. That confuses me, because if the `.htaccess` file is in the subdirectory, it should match. It does on my localhost anyway. You can try to match the entire thing, so with the subdirectory in the regex part.